# MySQL query working in Workbench but not on server

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT q.questions 
    ,a2.answers answer
    ,a.tally tally
FROM (
    SELECT idquestions
        ,MAX(tally) tally
    FROM answers
    GROUP BY idquestions
    ) a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT idanswers
        ,idquestions
        ,answers
        ,tally
    FROM answers
    ) a2 ON a2.idquestions = a.idquestions
    AND a2.tally = a.tally
LEFT JOIN questions q ON q.idquestions = a.idquestions
```

When called in Workbench, it does exactly as expected, but when called from my Node server, I get an empty response.

(EDIT) Here's the entire Node route:

```
var data = "";
connection.query("SELECT q.questions, a2.answers answer, a.tally tally FROM (SELECT idquestions, MAX(tally) tally FROM answers GROUP BY idquestions) a LEFT JOIN (SELECT idanswers, idquestions, answers, tally FROM answers) a2 ON a2.idquestions = a.idquestions AND a2.tally = a.tally LEFT JOIN questions q ON q.idquestions = a.idquestions",
      function(err, rows, fields){
    if(rows.length != 0){
        data = rows;
        res.json(data);  
    }else{
        data = 'No data Found..';
        res.json(data);
    }
      res.end();
});
```

});

Comment: I assume you're connecting to the same database...?

Comment: Potentially issue could be in your nodejs code, not query itself. Can you share it with us?

Comment: yes same database. the code should be fine, looks exactly like every other route I've made:

Comment: I'm not familiar with node.js, but that second subquery should not normally need to be a subquery (not that having it as such should change your final result).